# Google place api shows error in Android

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am facing a strange problem here.

I want to query the google places webservice from my andorid app.

For that I am always getting the error : "This service requires an API Key".

How ever when I try to query it using my chrome browser and the server key, I get the response properly.

In case of android, which key should I use as the android api key is giving me this error.

Adding a package name is optional :

[image: See here]

[image: This is the screenshot of the enabled api(s) for my app]

*Edit*

This is the request url :

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=cruise&key=AIzaSyDeFunLJQLF7WInuNnaWfbeyJzfw_1litQ
```

When i run this in browser I am getting this :

[image: Running in Chrome browser]

Sending the same request using hurl.it :

[image: Screen-1]

[image: Screen-2]

The exact error that I am getting @android app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Google Places Web API, you need to use a Server key.

The API is technically not meant for use in a client-side app, it's designed for websites to use.

You can use it in your app, however you will need to use a Server key that is not secured.

If you look at [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key), it clearly states:

> Note: The Google Places API Web Service does not work with an Android
> or iOS API key.

Official instructions:

> Alternatively, follow these steps to get an API key:
>
> Go to the Google Developers Console.
>
> Create or select a project.
>
> Click Continue to Enable the API.
>
> Go to Credentials to get a Server key (and set the API credentials).
>
> To prevent quota theft, secure your API key following these best practices.
> (Optional) Enable billing. See Usage Limits and Billing for more information.

Important:  leave the IP address field blank for using this webservice API directly from an app:

[image]

Edit:  Here is full code for Activity that is working and tested, you can use it as a reference to see if there is a problem in your code:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MapsActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback
{
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    SupportMapFragment mapFrag;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Use this one:
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps2);

        mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        mGoogleMap=googleMap;
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        StringBuilder sbValue = new StringBuilder(sbMethod());
        PlacesTask placesTask = new PlacesTask();
        placesTask.execute(sbValue.toString());
    }

    public StringBuilder sbMethod()
    {

        //use your current location here
        double mLatitude = 37.77657;
        double mLongitude = -122.417506;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
        sb.append("location=" + mLatitude + "," + mLongitude);
        sb.append("&radius=5000");
        sb.append("&types=" + "restaurant");
        sb.append("&sensor=true");

        sb.append("&key=AIza******************************");

        Log.d("Map", "url: " + sb.toString());

        return sb;
    }

    private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
    {

        String data = null;

        // Invoked by execute() method of this object
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            try {
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Start parsing the Google places in JSON format
            // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class ParserTask
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }
    }

    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException
    {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
        } finally {
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }

    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String, String>>> {

        JSONObject jObject;

        // Invoked by execute() method of this object
        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;
            Place_JSON placeJson = new Place_JSON();

            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

                places = placeJson.parse(jObject);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
            }
            return places;
        }

        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> list) {

            Log.d("Map", "list size: " + list.size());
            // Clears all the existing markers;
            mGoogleMap.clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                // Creating a marker
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

                // Getting a place from the places list
                HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = list.get(i);


                // Getting latitude of the place
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));

                // Getting longitude of the place
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));

                // Getting name
                String name = hmPlace.get("place_name");

                Log.d("Map", "place: " + name);

                // Getting vicinity
                String vicinity = hmPlace.get("vicinity");

                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                // Setting the position for the marker
                markerOptions.position(latLng);

                markerOptions.title(name + " : " + vicinity);

                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));

                // Placing a marker on the touched position
                Marker m = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

            }
        }
    }
    public class Place_JSON {

        /**
         * Receives a JSONObject and returns a list
         */
        public List<HashMap<String, String>> parse(JSONObject jObject) {

            JSONArray jPlaces = null;
            try {
                /** Retrieves all the elements in the 'places' array */
                jPlaces = jObject.getJSONArray("results");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            /** Invoking getPlaces with the array of json object
             * where each json object represent a place
             */
            return getPlaces(jPlaces);
        }

        private List<HashMap<String, String>> getPlaces(JSONArray jPlaces) {
            int placesCount = jPlaces.length();
            List<HashMap<String, String>> placesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            HashMap<String, String> place = null;

            /** Taking each place, parses and adds to list object */
            for (int i = 0; i < placesCount; i++) {
                try {
                    /** Call getPlace with place JSON object to parse the place */
                    place = getPlace((JSONObject) jPlaces.get(i));
                    placesList.add(place);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return placesList;
        }

        /**
         * Parsing the Place JSON object
         */
        private HashMap<String, String> getPlace(JSONObject jPlace)
        {

            HashMap<String, String> place = new HashMap<String, String>();
            String placeName = "-NA-";
            String vicinity = "-NA-";
            String latitude = "";
            String longitude = "";
            String reference = "";

            try {
                // Extracting Place name, if available
                if (!jPlace.isNull("name")) {
                    placeName = jPlace.getString("name");
                }

                // Extracting Place Vicinity, if available
                if (!jPlace.isNull("vicinity")) {
                    vicinity = jPlace.getString("vicinity");
                }

                latitude = jPlace.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lat");
                longitude = jPlace.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lng");
                reference = jPlace.getString("reference");

                place.put("place_name", placeName);
                place.put("vicinity", vicinity);
                place.put("lat", latitude);
                place.put("lng", longitude);
                place.put("reference", reference);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return place;
        }
    }

}
```

activity_maps2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        tools:context="com.iotaconcepts.aurum.MapsActivity2"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Using the server keys gives rise to the same error.

Comment: Did you leave the IP address field blank?

Comment: yes, I did. See the response screenshot that I added to the main question

Comment: You should be using GET, not POST.  Everything goes in the query string in the url.

Comment: I was sleeping!! Thanks a lot! :P

Answer (score 0):

under credentials choose api key, than android key

Comment: Did that, and that doesn't help. As I said in the question, using the android api key also gives the same message.

Comment: it says the package name is optional, see the screenshot I added

Comment: no, just add your package name and fingerprint and enjoy :)