# Google places not displaying

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places

Im working on a small mobile application that should allow the user to find local places close to where they currently are. These places include restaurants, cafes, bakerys etc. Ive done some implementation and managed to get my location working, added the google places code but for some reason nothing seems to show up on my map:

```
package com.example.test.outandabout;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

    GoogleMap mMap;
    Spinner mSprPlaceType;

    String[] mPlaceType = null;
    String[] mPlaceTypeName = null;

    double mLatitude = 0;
    double mLongitude = 0;
    HashMap<String, String> mMarkerPlaceLink = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private Intent intent;
    private String type;
    private Object marker;
    private LatLng l;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mMap = mapFragment.getMap();
// Enabling MyLocation in Google Map
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Getting LocationManager object from System Service
        // LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Getting the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Getting Current Location From GPS
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        // onLocationChanged(location);
        if (location != null) {
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);


        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(
                "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
        sb.append("location=" + mLatitude + "," + mLongitude);
        sb.append("&radius=3000");
        sb.append("&types=restaurant");
        sb.append("&sensor=true");
        sb.append("&key=PLACES_KEY");
        // Creating a new non-ui thread task to download Google place json
        // data
        PlacesTask placesTask = new PlacesTask();

        // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class PlaceTask
        placesTask.execute(sb.toString());
        // Setting click event lister for the find button

    }


    /**
     * A method to download json data from url
     */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    iStream));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        } finally {
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }

        return data;
    }


    /**
     * A class, to download Google Places
     */
    private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        String data = null;

        // Invoked by execute() method of this object
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            try {
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Start parsing the Google places in JSON format
            // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class ParseTask
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }

    }

    /**
     * A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format
     */
    private class ParserTask extends
            AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String, String>>> {

        JSONObject jObject;

        // Invoked by execute() method of this object
        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(
                String... jsonData) {

            List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;
            PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();

            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

                /** Getting the parsed data as a List construct */
                places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
            }
            return places;
        }

        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> list) {

            // Clears all the existing markers
            mMap.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                // Creating a marker
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

                // Getting a place from the places list
                HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = list.get(i);

                // Getting latitude of the place
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));

                // Getting longitude of the place
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));

                // Getting name
                String name = hmPlace.get("place_name");

                // Getting vicinity
                String vicinity = hmPlace.get("vicinity");

                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                // Setting the position for the marker
                markerOptions.position(latLng);

                markerOptions.title(name + " : " + vicinity);

                // Placing a marker on the touched position
                Marker m = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

                // Linking Marker id and place reference

                mMarkerPlaceLink.put(m.getId(), hmPlace.get("reference"));

            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}
```

My Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test.outandabout">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.test.outandabout.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Not sure why the markers arent appearing on map
any help will be appreicated

Edit:

In the logs, I'm getting this error message:

> json response: { "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile
>   application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received
>   from IP address xx.xx.xx.xx, with empty referer", "html_attributions"
>   : [], "results" : [], "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}

Comment: Add a log entry to log the value of `data` after the call to `data = sb.toString();` to make sure you're getting valid JSON back.

Comment: Would that just be Log(data)?

Comment: `Log.d("data", "json response: " + data); `

Comment: For some reason it says `json response: {   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address xx.xx.xx.xx, with empty referer",   "html_attributions" : [],   "results" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}`

Comment: You need to use a Server Key with no restrictions for the Places Web API, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34514805/google-place-api-shows-error-in-android

Comment: Ah got it working with a browser key but without a referer, isnt that a little unsecure?

Comment: Yes, it is unsecure.  For a production quality implementation, the recommendation is to have a proxy server in the middle that makes the API calls (the Server API key lives on the server), and have the app only interface with the proxy server.